# What is WPC.BizTalk.Component.NCPDP.dll? Is it a third party dll?

Tags: dll, components, integration, biztalk, biztalk-2013

I just want to know some info about this DLL **WPC.BizTalk.Component.NCPDP.dll**. As I need this in one of my BizTalk projects to get them successfully build.

Comment: Related: [NCPDP D.0 Schemas](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2684e0fe-6570-47df-a2aa-14d556bb0c7d/ncpdp-d0-schemas?forum=biztalkediandas2) (... and first result when searching for this name).

Comment: That does not look like a standard BizTalk DLL.  So either it is a custom component by a third party or one created by whichever developer created that solution.   If you are making a change to an existing solution, this DLL should exist in your testing & prod environments

Comment: Thank you very much for your response but we can't contact the developer as he is not part of the company now. Is there any way that we can find out that is this a third party custom component or not?